# How to find max number of columns and rows from array in php

Tags: php

I upload a csv and expload it to an array.

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(64) "Criteron A-1 bla ,Criteron A-2 bla,Criteron A-3 bla,Criteron A-4 bla,Criteron A-5 bla"
  [1]=>
  string(64) "Criteron B-1 bla,Criteron B-2 bla,Criteron B-3 bla,Criteron B-4 bla,Criteron B-5 bla"
  [2]=>
  string(51) "Criteron C-1 bla,Criteron C-2 bla,Criteron C-3 bla,Criteron C-4 bla"
  [3]=>
  string(38) "Criteron D-1 bla,Criteron D-2 bla,Criteron D-3 bla"
  [4]=>
  string(64) "Criteron E-1,Criteron E-2,Criteron E-3,Criteron E-4,Criteron E-5"
  [5]=>
  string(51) "Criteron F-1,Criteron F-2,Criteron F-3,Criteron F-4"
}
```

The original csv has 6 rows and max 5 columns as you see in the above.

In order to put these data in a table, I need to know number of rows and maximum number of columns.

I can find number of rows by using count(). I am thinking to use substr_count() of comma "," for each array and find max then add one to that max to find out the max number of column. (I haven't figure it out how to code the second part yet, though)

I am wondering if you know a better way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the max number of columns using `max()`, `array_map()` and `explode()`

```
$maxColumns = max(array_map(function($row){
    return count(explode(',', $row));
}, $rows));
```

1. `array_map` runs the anonymous function for every row in the array, creating a new array with its results.
2. For each row, `count(explode())` counts the number of columns seperated by commas in it.
3. `max()` runs on the array of column counts, returning the largest one.

Answer (score 4):

When you read the file into memory you should use the [`fgetscsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function. It will parse the data much more effectively than a simple `explode()` or `substr()` based approach, considering many edge cases and CSV features like quoted strings.

You can keep a running count of columns as you load it:

```
$maxCols = 0;
$fileData = array();
$fileName = 'myfile.csv';

$fp = fopen($fileName, 'r');
for ($numRows = 0; ($line = fgetcsv($fp, 8192)) !== FALSE; $numRows++) {
  $lineCols = count($line);
  if ($lineCols > $maxCols) $maxCols = $lineCols;
  $fileData[] = $line;
}

echo "Rows: $numRows; Cols: $maxCols; Data: ";
var_dump($fileData);
```

As a side note, a properly formatted CSV file should really contain an equal number of columns on each line - it is supposed to be a text based representation of a table, and tables should have a definite set of columns and a variable number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you explode the rows further into individual entries, it's trivial to count the maximum number of columns:

```
// explode further
$rows = array_map(function ($row) { return explode(',', $row); }, $rows);

// count
$cols = max(array_map('count', $rows));
$rows = count($rows);
```

Note: PHP 5.3+ syntax.

Comment: almost identical to my answer

Comment: @deceze: Aren't lines in a CSV file supposed to have the same number of columns (even if some are empty)?  If so, wouldn't using `count()` on the first line be sufficient instead of iterating all lines?

Comment: @drrcknlsn *Supposedly* yes, but the OP doesn't seem to think so. :) I upvoted Dave's answer though, since he's correct on all points, including that one.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should read csv files with [fgetcsv](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) (it should handle all delimiters correctly so you don't have to care about lines such as: `1,2,'Text containing don''t and so on'`.

Than you can use `foreach` to go trough all items, or use `max(array_map('count', $rows))`.